# What's wrong with the commons-fileupload dependency?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I'm trying to use commons-fileupload module by including its dependency in `pom.xml`. Packaging has no problem, however, when starting the web-app, it causes the "NoClassDefFound" error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
```

Here's my pom.xml config:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, I included following config in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: THe error message will name the class that's not being found, and that bit of information should help you just as it would help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the deployed web-app to see if the JAR file is present.  (It should be in the webapp's WEB-INF/lib directory.)  If it is missing, check the WAR file contents, and then the maven sandbox you used to create it.

(If you really did manage to package the WAR properly, you've probably run into a deployment glitch.)

Comment: thanks, I found the problem, I'm running Tomcat in Eclipse and it seems there are some errors. When I package the web app by maven command and deploy it directly, the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: I don't trust m2eclipse to build and deploy my WAR files.  Burned too many times.  I build and deploy from the command line.